Python debugging in a non-default conda env via WSL2 in Visual Studio Code
I am running a program through the bash terminal via WSL in Visual Studio Code. I want to debug using the built-in VS Code debugger. However, the Python debugger in VS Code runs a Windows command, even though I am using WSL. It also doesn't look for the right Python interpreter.
I have changed the settings configuration of launch.json:
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "debugpy",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": true,
        "python": "/home/mptouzel/miniconda3/envs/socsan2/bin/python"
    }
]

which in principle should fix the version issue (it doesn't look like it does, so maybe I need to configure something else?), but the main issue is that it doesn't even seem to realize I am running WSL and so in a bash terminal of course a windows command won't work.
All the partial solutions I have found don't seem to have any effect.
